# OpenStack Install on Ubuntu 14.04 VM

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, cloud, openstack

I want to install and learn openstack. I have two ESX Hosts at the moment and a small NAS environment (capable of iscsi, nfs and cifs).

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

The above document seems to be fairly straight forward to follow, but I have a few questions:

a) Can I follow the above instructions in a virtualized environment?
b) I can create 6 Virtual Machines with 1 x dual-homed (Dual Nics) VM
c) Can we use XEN instead of KVM?
d) MAAS - Metal as a Service - Would this work?

or

I would have to do it manually as i am planning to do this in a virtual environment?

will be grateful for your expert suggestions / tips - thanks
Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

The single install uses only LXC and KVM. XEN isn't supported at this time.